# Why my Google Drive API access auto revoked?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-apps

I have some problem with Google Drive API access: my access revoked every week!
What I have done:

1. Created an app in Google Cloud Platform.
2. Enabled Google API.
3. Created a service account for my app.
4. Created OAuth 2.0 client secret for third-party apps.

I have some files on my home server that I want to upload to my Google Drive once a day. When I request access to my Google Drive (I'm requesting offline access) I can work with my drive without any problems. Also, I can see my app in my Google Account third-party apps tab. But after a week I see that my app just disappearing from the third-party apps tab in Google Account and my server receives that access and refresh tokens are expired. This happened to me already 4 times!

The only thing that is strange is that when I'm requesting access Google says that this app is "untrusted" and "if I am sure that I want to give the access". If so, how can I make the app trusted?

How can I give permanent access to my Google Drive for my app? I only need this for my account, not for other people, because only I using this cloud app. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. After the first time access was granted to my app, a new option appeared in my Google Account called "Access for untrusted third-party apps". I need to enable this option and grand access for my app again. After that my app appeared in an untrusted section of my Google Account but no access revoke by Google for now.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is still in testing it will also be revoked after a week [Expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)

[image]

Comment: No, my app is published.